# Have you successfully installed Active Directory Management Gateway Service on 2008?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, gateway, service

I've got a pair of 2008 DCs onto which I've been trying to install the Active Directory Management Gateway Service.  (I only wanted it on one but when that didn't work I tried another.)

Both are failing with: "The update does not apply to your system".

They're both Windows Server 2008 Domain Controllers, x64 version.  Both have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on them.  One has Service Pack 2 installed and the other has the hotfix from 967574 installed. Both servers were rebooted after the installed of each of the required
updates.

I have attempted to install Windows6.0-KB968934-x64.msu on both and get the error reported above.  According to [the docs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=008940c6-0296-4597-be3e-1d24c1cf0dda&displayLang=en), my machines meet the requirements, so something must be missing from the requirements.  Or there's something odd about these DCs.

Has anyone succeeded?  If so, did you have to install/remove anything (else) to get it installed?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Haven't had any time to investigate further.

Comment: Glad I'm not alone.  Is your DC on SP2 or 967574?  Did you build yours yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed a para in the original instructions which referred to hotfix 969166.  Having looked at it again, I think I must've read the first few words of that paragraph, which mentioned 2003, and skipped it.  I guess the guy who was writing the para knew it was about .net so grouped 2003 and 2008 together - he was thinking from his pov, rather than from ours.

I installed that hotfix, had another go and it worked.